# Lyx Moving Pagination to Top Right in an Inserted PDF

Tags: lyx, page-numbering, pdfpages

I am preparing a thesis that includes a publication after the appendix. I have been able to correctly insert the PDF of the publication as well as number it. However, the page numbers appear in the middle of the bottom of the PDF's pages. I would like to be able to move these to the top right of the page.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: So how did you insert the PDF? Insert --> File --> External Material --> PDFpages?

Comment: Just realized something: did you add pagenumbering using something like `pagecommand={\thispagestyle{plain}}`, or was the page numbers already present in the PDF?